# image before text button

Tags: html, css

I tried to have an image with text in a button. But I can't get the text after the button. Now I have the problem that the text keeps going under the image.

I don't want the picture in my css but I want to keep the css code so I can duplicate it.

Here is the html part and the css code

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: silver;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 11px 32px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-image-width: 14px;
}

.tab button {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 24px;
}

.tab img {
  width: 5%;
  height: 1%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <h2><button class="tablinks" onclick="openPage('Afghanistan')"><img src="images/Afghanistan.png" alt="Afghanistan Flag" >Afghanistan</button></h2>
</div>
<div id="Afghanistan" class="tabcontent">
  <iframe src="Afghanistan.html" width="700">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

this is how it looks, if you click on it an iframe of another page will go under

[image]

Comment: using your image as a background image would be easier. Why don't you want it in your css?

Comment: Cause i will use the css code for multiple images for the same sizes. i will use it to get the country flags before the text

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the question. But maybe you can use [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: Do you want text after the button or after the image - it's not quite clear what your end goal is

Comment: @Oram You can put all the reusable code in one class and make a seperate class for each country with there flag.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I know. However, in the question he specifically asks not to put the image in the CSS and complains about the text being hidden by the image. Given these constraints, trying to change the z-index might solve the problem.

Comment: @oram `z-index` only works on positioned elements `position:absolute`, `position:relative` or `position:fixed`

Comment: @MarkBaijens or flex items (children of an element with display: flex). You can have a look at the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) I provided.

Comment: @Oram true, but if you want to support older versions of ie you can't use flex. Also for flex it works a bit different. It's a pretty new thing. In a few years it should be pretty mainstream though.

Comment: @MarkBaijens Since we don't **really** know what the requirements are, we can let the OP read about z-index, decide if it's a good idea and try to work it out. If it was up to me I would probably do it like you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You can put all the reusable code in one class and make a seperate class for each country with their flag.

Just set the correct padding so the text won't be placed on the background image.

```css
.tab {
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the buttons inside the tab */

.tab button {
  background-color: silver;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 24px 10px 60px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: inherit;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.tab button.afghanistan {
  background-image: url('https://d1nhio0ox7pgb.cloudfront.net/_img/v_collection_png/32x32/shadow/flag_afghanistan.png');
}

.tab button.netherlands {
  background-image: url('https://d1nhio0ox7pgb.cloudfront.net/_img/v_collection_png/32x32/shadow/flag_netherlands.png');
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */

.tab button:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Create an active/current tablink class */

.tab button.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}


/* Style the tab content */

.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-image-width: 14px;
}

.tab button {
  
}

.tab img {
  width: 5%;
  height: 1%;
  margin-left: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab">
  <h2><button class="tablinks afghanistan" onclick="openPage('Afghanistan')">Afghanistan</button></h2>
  <h2><button class="tablinks netherlands" onclick="openPage('Netherlands')">Netherlands</button></h2>
</div>
<div id="Afghanistan" class="tabcontent">
  <iframe src="Afghanistan.html" width="700">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This will work for me. thanks alot :) you make my life easier now :P

Comment: @Crystas Your welcome, please accept the answer if it answers your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should float your image left.

Comment: this part is making the  image smaller or bigger. .tab img {
  width: 5%;
  height: 1%;

Answer (score 0):

Add display: inline; in .tab img like this.
.tab img {
   width: 5%;
   height: 1%;
   margin-left: 5px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline;
}

Comment: You can just edit your last posted answer instead of giving another answer to question.